# Set RowCount but not ColumnCount in TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

The purpose of this winform is to display the `DataTable` so that every column in `tableLayoutPanel1` is composed of four cells; each one with the four colors below. And each cell will have the *WorkNum*.

I know how many rows will be shown (four, in this case), but I want the control to manage how many columns will be displayed. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to set the `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` so that every column has four rows. In other words, I can set the rowCount, but not the columnCount

The `DataTable` looks like the following:

```
Color       WorkNum
-------------------
Yellow      4304
Blue        4593
Green       4346
Orange      8775
Yellow      8464
Blue        3515
Green       5426
Orange      9452
Yellow      2012
Blue        0546
Green       0551
Orange      0144
```

The winform with `dataGridView1` and `tableLayoutPanel` looks like this. Everything works correct; the *only issue* is that I need to set the rowCount:

```
public partial class FormMonitor : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

    public FormMonitor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillGrid();
    }
    private void FillGrid()
    {
        DataTable tableColors = GetData(connString);
        dataGridView1.DataSourceChanged += dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tableColors;
    }
    private void dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            UcColor ucb = new UcColor(row, tableLayoutPanel1);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ucb);
        }
        tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

The user control looks like the following:

```
public partial class UcColor : UserControl
{
    public UcColor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public UcColor(DataRow row, TableLayoutPanel CellsFLP)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = Color.FromName(row["color"].ToString());
        label1.Text = row["WorkNum"].ToString();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

I had initially started with `FlowLayoutPanel`, and at the right height (enough height to fit four cells), it works like a charm. But once the height is too much, then everything moves around.

I would appreciate it if I can use the existing code. For reasons beyond this example I can't use a `DataGridView`.

This is what it needs to look like. With the current code, everything's correct, but I just can't set the number of rows to be displayed.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't understand the issue. Why won't you just use `tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4;` and then add the RowStyles one by one? You can increase the `.ColumnCount` on each 4 rows added, so that they could dynamically become more, if I've understood correctly.

Comment: I dragged & dropped a `TableLayoutPanel`, and I set `tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4;` just below `tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();`. It only shows me 4 cells, like in the url here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8wBxo.png

Comment: You need to set the rowcount before you add controls. And if you want them to be place correctly, you should be defining a possition in your `.Add` method. And after each four cells added, you may want to create a new column. I'm not sure if they're not created automatically tho, but it's better to play it safe when not sure. ATM I'm from a phone, but I can assist you later if noone has helped further.

Comment: It seems that the columns are automatically added, so there's no need to set `ColumnCount` or explicitly run `tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add()`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you managed to fix your issue or not? Because I can give you an example of how to achieve it now.

Comment: It's not necessary. Your comment was very helpful.  Thanks again.